# Html Agility Pack foreach getting same result code with parsing

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

Hi i'm trying to parse the html code down below to get both the ip and port like this

So it should be like this

```
IP:50.18.182.20 > Port: 443

IP:162.248.50.159 > Port: 80
```

But am keep getting it

```
IP:50.18.182.20 > Port: 443

IP:162.248.50.159 > Port: 443
```

The port should match the ones they are with not both using the same ports..?

Any help is awesome thanks.

Here is html

```html
<td><a title="Proxy details">50.18.182.20</a></td>
<td>443</td>
<td>
High Anonymous Proxy.
</td>
<td>HTTP, HTTPS</td>
<td><img alt="United States" title="United States" src="http://flagpedia.net/data/flags/mini/us.png" />&nbsp;United States</td>
<td>San Francisco, California</td>
<td>15s</td>
<td>32.88%</td>
<td>10 Minutes ago.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a title="Proxy details">162.248.50.159</a></td>
<td>80</td>
<td>
High Anonymous Proxy.
</td>
<td>HTTP, HTTPS</td>
<td><img alt="United States" title="United States" src="http://flagpedia.net/data/flags/mini/us.png" />&nbsp;United States</td>
<td>West Chester, Pennsylvania</td>
<td>8s</td>
<td>73.97%</td>
<td>1 Hour, 4 Minutes ago.</td>
```

And C# code

```cs
var htmlD = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@title='Proxy details']");
var numberProxies = htmlD.Count;

for (var index = 0; index < numberProxies; index++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("IP: " + htmlD[index].InnerText + " > Port: "+
                  htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td")[1].InnerText);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You should get an `index was out of range` error, since your counter should be `var numberProxies = htmlD.Count - 1;`. Just use a `foreach` loop there.

Comment: Am not getting that error though

Comment: updated the code to something i just thought of but getting the same result.

Comment: Well i actually got IP:50.18.182.20 > Port: 80; IP:162.248.50.159 > Port: 80 for that

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get port number from `<td>` tag next to the one contains anchor you've found, but doing it incorrectly.

In fact, you're selecting first `<td>` of document here: `.SelectNodes("//td")[1]` all the time.

Try to replace

```
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td")[1].InnerText
```

with

```
htmlD[index].ParentNode.NextSibling.NextSibling.InnerText
```

and it will work as intended.

Comment: THANK YOU!,Srs thank been working on this for like hours finally got it to work :D

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the same result, as your second query, whilst it uses context, doesn't relate to the loop you're iterating

Instead, think about it logically,

```
// get the rows that contain proxies
var proxies = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[td/a[@title='Proxy details']]");

if (proxies != null)
{
    foreach (var proxy in proxies)
    {
        // process this proxy row
        Console.WriteLine("IP:" + proxy.SelectSingleNode(td/a[@title='Proxy details']).InnerText);
        Console.WriteLine("PORT:" + proxy.SelectSingleNode(td[2]).InnerText);
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

In XPath when using `//` you look for the any instance of the node through out the entire document therefore effectively out of context and incorrectly bringing back the first Port. Try search within context:

You can try using the `[NextSibling][1]` method in `HtmlNode`

Answer (score 0):

You can see `<td>` containing port as the first following-sibling of `<td>` containing `"Proxy details"` :

```
var htmlD = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[a/@title='Proxy details']");
var numberProxies = htmlD.Count;

foreach(HtmlNode node in htmlD)
{
    var ip = node.InnerText;
    var port = node.SelectSingleNode("following-sibling::td[1]").InnerText;
    Console.WriteLine("IP: {0} > Port: {1}", ip, port);
}
```